# Cómo obtener el código escrito en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

En javascript puedo obtener el contenido de una función con `funcion.toString()`,

Pero como obtengo todo el código escrito ? Intenté con `window.toString()`, pero no funciona. Sé que podria encerrar todo el código en una `IIFE`, pero eso ya lo sé, busco un método para obtener todo el código de window, con `"código de window"` me refiero al **mismo código que escribo**, inclusive la misma función `toString()` que lo está escribiendo.

```js
var amak = 20;


function m(){
  var a = "hola";
}



const n = [];
      
      
      
      
console.log(window.toString());
```

Comment: intenta con JSON.stringfy

Comment: Cuando dices todo el código, ¿te refieres también al HTML? ¿O a todo el código dentro del `script` que se está ejecutando? ¿O a todo el código de todos los ficheros JS/scripts inline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes obtener el script ([HTMLScriptElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement)) actual con [document.currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) y obtener su propiedad text.

```js
const hello = 'world';      

console.log(document.currentScript.text);
```

Comment: hahah puse `console.log(eval(document.currentScript.text));` y petó el navegador xD